# Bootstrap Navbar Brand image gets pushed down upon collapse

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar brand image gets pushed down when I resize my screen to simulate mobile.  How can I use media queries to resize the navbar-header (since I think it's the one that doesn't resize and forces the brand image to go down)?

```
   <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"style="margin-top:27px;">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" style="">
           <%=image_tag "elem_logo-white.png", :style => "width: 95%;"%> 
          </a>
   </div>
```

[image]
[image]

I did this line of code however it did not work. The image became smaller, however the navbar still fragmented.
    @media (max-width:768px){
     .navbar-brand img{
       width:100px!important;
     }
    }

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by editing Peter Wilson's suggestion.
Here's what worked:

```
    @media (max-width:768px){
        .navbar-brand{
       width:70vw!important;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to give it smaller width on small screens like

```
@media (max-width:768px){
 .navbar-brand img{
   width:100px;
   max-height:50px;
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work :( I uploaded the result.

Comment: bootstrap nav bar has a height of 50px; try something like this 
.navbar-brand img{
   max-height:50px;
 }
 and it should work if not please post a valid html code to enable us debug it for you

Answer (score 0):

I use a large logo and use the following code and css for mine:

style.css

```
.logo-img {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

header.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"><img class="logo-img" src="PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Where PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE is the picture

Answer (score 0):

Apparently none above worked until I put the `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom`, this pushes the contrained image at the bottom to be above the navbar bottom and align without protruding outside.

```
 @media(max-width: 768px){
    .navbar-brand img{
      width: 100px;
      max-height: 60px;
      /*padding-bottom: 20px;*/
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
  }
```